# How to get the result of executing a function inside it, make a transformation and return

Tags: javascript, function, promise, closures

The Add function is called by the user in the external environment. It is necessary that the called Add function is executed and the resulting value is converted to a number and returned as a response from the called Add function to the external environment.

```js
function Ext() {
  let cs = 0;

  function pars(fn) {
    let newFn = fn.bind(null);

    function cal(...num) {
      newFn = newFn.bind(null, ...num);
      return cal;
    }

    cal.toString = () => newFn();

    return (...num) => {
      newFn = fn.bind(null);
      return cal(...num);
    };
  }

  const _add = pars((...num) => {
    num.forEach((item) => { cs += item; });
    return num.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  });

  return {
    add: function add(...num) {
      if ([...num].length === 0) return add;
      return _add(...num);
    }
    /*
    add: function(...num) {
       function add(...num) {
        if ([...num].length === 0) return add;
        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          let result = _add(...num);
          resolve(result);
        });
        return promise;
      }
      
      add(...num).then(function(result) { Number(result) });
    },
    */
  }
}

const ext = Ext();

console.log(ext.add()); //function
console.log(ext.add(1)); //1
console.log(ext.add(3, 1)()(3)); //7

console.log(typeof ext.add(1)); //function
let one = ext.add(1);
console.log(one === 1); //false
console.log(Number(one) === 1); //true
console.log(typeof one) //function
console.log(typeof 1) //number
```

That is, the add function externally returns a number, but it is a function by type. It is necessary that the function ultimately return exactly the number: console.log (typeof ext.add (1)) // Number P. S. The commented code in the question is an attempt to make the function return exactly the number.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  In what way does the code shown not work as expected?

Comment: @David The add function returns a number whose type is a function, but the type needs to be a number.

Comment: "external environment": what is that? Your code *explicitly* returns `add` when no argument is provided, so yes that is a function. It is not clear from your question what the expected output is for the script you have given. I have no idea which outputs are like you want it, and which not.

Comment: @trincot By the external environment I meant that the number of arguments to the function and its execution is carried out by someone else, and not inside the program, so you cannot do something like ```Number (add (1) (2))```. So I was trying to do the conversion inside the function (see the commented out code).

Comment: @trincot When no arguments are passed, the function must return itself.
When arguments are passed, the function returns the result in numeric form, but if you look at the return type, even though the result looks like a number, it is a function. (Pay attention to the ```console.log ()```, which I gave as an example, it may become clearer).

Comment: Your script ends with comments next to each console log. Is that the expected output or the wrong output?

Comment: @trincot This is the actual log. This will be displayed if you run the code.
The main problem is this:
What is now:
```console.log (typeof ext.add (1)); // Function```
What is necessary:
```console.log (typeof ext.add (1)); // Number```

Comment: If you want `ext.add(1)` to be *callable*, like `ext.add(1)()`, then by the specification `typeof` will always return "function" (see [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-typeof-operator-results))

Comment: @trincot The fact of the matter is that I want the function to be called once, but by currying, for example ```console.log (ext.add (3, 1) () (3)); // 7```. But the result of the returned function must be of type number, and must not be called. It is possible?

Comment: No, that is not possible. There are intermediate results: `ext.add(3, 1)`. You could imagine storing that in a temp variable `temp` and then decide to continue `temp()`, ...etc. This consistency that is baked into JS prevents you from identifying beforehand what the "endpoint" is of this chain. At least I don't see anything in your question that defines when the endpoint is reached (end of currying).

Comment: @trincot Got it, thanks a lot!

Comment: One way out of this, is to agree that if you call the intermediate function with zero arguments, that that indicates the end point: `ext.add(3, 1)` will return a function, but `ext.add(3, 1)()` will return the value, and no more chaining will be allowed. So, you would have to do `ext.add(3, 1)(3)()` to get that 7.

Comment: @trincot And can I somehow determine how arguments are passed to the function inside it - as usual: ```ext.add(1, 2, 3)```, or by currying ```ext.add(1)(2)(3)```?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Use parameter spread syntax: `(...args)` and then `if (args.length)` ...etc.

Comment: @trincot Exactly, thank you!